# How to process C++ files using a Python script in an Xcode project

Tags: python, c++, xcode

I am trying to create a custom build rule in Xcode 5.1.1 that will cause all C++ files to be processed using a Python script. I went to the "Build Rules" section and added a custom script. For some reason the script is never ran. This is the code in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

path = "~/Desktop/output.txt"
full_path = os.path.expanduser(path)
file = open(full_path, "a+")
file_name = sys.argv[1]
file.write("Processing file: " + file_name + "\n")
file.close()
```

I made this python script executable like this: chmod +x myscript.py.

I then added the full path of the script to the custom script section in Xcode. When I build my project after cleaning it the custom script is never executed. What needs to be changed for all C++ files in my target to be processed by the script?

Comment: After you try to build your project, go to the Report Navigator view and look at the build log.  Do you see an entry for your script?  Do you see any errors or other messages?

Comment: I did not see an entry for the script. I see no other messages.